# best web framework for go

Tags: angularjs, react, go

I am new to Go (GoLang). Working on small learning project.
I did the basic of Go.
Started Gin as web framework.

My problem start with frontend. Is ReactJS/Angular is the only option?
Anything like JSP/JSF/Struts for Java.
ASP.net for C#
Anything from Go.

if not then Gin is right path and between ReactJS/Angular which is the best or something else.

regards